# How to scrape text from websites using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, text-mining

I wrote a code in python using 'requests' and 'beautifulSoup' api to scrape text data from first 100 sites return by google.
Well it works good on most of sites but it is giving errors on those which are responding later or not responding at all 
I am getting this error

*raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.lfpress.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /2015/11/06/fair-with-a-flare-samosas-made-easy (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))*

Am I supposed to change code written inside requests API? Or I need to use some proxy? How can I leave that site and move on to next one? As error is stopping my execution.

Comment: try:.. except: pass ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "try except" block around your call to catch that exception and continue if you don't care about the error like:

```
import requests
try:
    requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
except requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError as e:
    print repr(e)
```

Comment: Well thanks, How can I avoid all exceptions present in requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions? Not just MaxRetryError?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan That's called passive error handling. Use `except` alone without specifying.

Comment: To expand ^, you can write except Exception as e: smth smth e